# How to copy values from one table into a different table multiple times

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a range of dates repeated multiple times.

```
Dates
2016-11-01
2016-11-02
2016-11-03
2016-11-01
2016-11-02
2016-11-03
2016-11-01
2016-11-02
2016-11-03
```

I have a second column which is currently empty. I am trying to copy the values from another table into each date range. It should look something like this:

```
Dates              Values
2016-11-01     1
2016-11-02     1
2016-11-03     1
2016-11-01     2
2016-11-02     2
2016-11-03     2
2016-11-01     3
2016-11-02     3
2016-11-03     3
```

The actual values are not sequential though. I have tried using INSERT, but that adds new rows. I need to modify the existing rows. I also tried using UPDATE, but I end up with the same value being saved to multiple date ranges. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: sounds like something that you should not be doing.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: care you explain the requirement to copy from one table to another?

Comment: The values are getting stored in a pre-existing table. The pre-existing table has millions of entries, but I need only a small subset of the values. It is not practical to modify that table, which is why I'm try to make a new table so that I can associate the date ranges with values.

Comment: so that means you have a criteria to select a subset of rows from that table. So why not just use the criteria to select them at display time. There's no need to duplicate and duplication will lead to inconsistencies when the orginal data changes.

Comment: The values will not be displayed to the user. I need them to perform further operations. I am not concerned about duplication causing inconsistencies because the original data never gets edited.

Comment: what you really need is a VIEW http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html

Comment: The existing code base which I have to work with is already using temporary tables for these queries. Since the data in the temporary tables will be used for multiple queries each session, it is my understanding that they are more suitable than a view.

Comment: Temporary tables last only for the life time of that particular session, so without knowing more about your application I cannot comment whether it's suitable or not.

Comment: Well regardless of whether I use a temporary table, is there a way to copy the values in the way described above?